# Remove the annoying screenshot pop up?

Tags: screen-capture, ios

Is there any way to remove that annoying screenshot pop up after you take a screenshot?

I was trying to play a game after updating to iOS 11 and it ruined my game thanks to not being able to tap the bottom part of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can’t disable the screenshot overlay as if iOS 11.0 you can swipe it away.

1. Take a screenshot
2. As soon as the screenshot overlay appears **swipe it to the left**. You will be able to tap the area occupied by the screenshot without having to wait for the screenshot(s) to disappear.